# Using ng-repeat {{x.name}} The marks should update if a user edits any single slot of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**AngularJS code**

This is my code in AngularJS that I want to correct. Currently in the last rows of the table I print out the name and marks of the student with the highest marks. I want the name and score to change if a user edits the preprogrammed marks.

Example: The 2nd highest person becomes the highest if the highest is changed to 0

```
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{
    {       
        var x=[];   
        for (var i = 0; i<20; i++)
        {
            var R = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10);  
            x[i]=R;
        }   
    };

$scope.names = [
    {name:'Priya',age:'19',gender:'Female',English:x[0], Hindi:x[1]},
    ....
    {name:'Jiah', age:'18', gender:'Female',English:x[18],Hindi:x[19]}
    ];

$scope.sortColumn ="name";

$scope.avg = function(e, h){
 if(!h) h=0;
 if(!e) e=0;
 return ( parseInt(h)+parseInt(e))/2;
}

$scope.delete = function (name) 

{
    $scope.names.splice( $scope.names.indexOf(name), 1 );
}   

});
</script>
```

**HTML Code**
This is the code where I want the changes to occur. At the bottom of the HTML code you can see where I want the highest marks for Hindi and English.

```
  <table>   


    <tr ng-repeat ="x in names | orderBy:sortColumn">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.age}}</td>
        <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.English"></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.Hindi"></td>
        <td>
            <button><a href="" ng-click="delete(x)" style="text-decoration:none;">Delete</a></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table ng-model="total">
    <tr><td>The total is: {{total}}</td></tr>
```

Below is where I want the highest marks in English then Hindi to appear.

```
    <tr><td ng-repeat="x in names |orderBy:'-English' | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}} has the highest marks in English: {{x.English}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td ng-repeat="x in names |orderBy:'-Hindi' | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}} has the highest marks in Hindi: {{x.Hindi}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you update the inputs, the model is set to "string" instead of "number".

You should change the type from "text" to "number".

```
<td><input type="number" ng-model="x.English"></td>
<td><input type="number" ng-model="x.Hindi"></td>
```

Also to properly ordering empty values:

```
<tr><td ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:['!-English', '-English']  | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}} has the highest marks in English: {{x.English}}</td></tr>
<tr><td ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:['!-Hindi', '-Hindi'] | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}} has the highest marks in Hindi: {{x.Hindi}}</td></tr>
```

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fk5zjuq8/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using ngRepeat, you can create another function which will return the student with the highest value in a certain subject:

```
$scope.highestStudent = function(key) {
    return $scope.names.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev[key] > curr[key] ? prev : curr;
    });
}
```

Using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) we are reducing the Array into a single result: which of these Students, has the highest value in a certain subject.

With this, we can use this instead to display the result:

```
<tr><td> {{highestStudent('English').name}} has the highest marks in English: {{highestStudent('English').English}}</td></tr>
<tr><td> {{highestStudent('Hindi').name}} has the highest marks in Hindi: {{highestStudent('Hindi').Hindi}}</td></tr>
```